# pep8 compliance testing is failing

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pep8

I've followed Head First Python 2nd Edition and a pep8 compliance testing is demonstrated in chapter 4.

When running  **py.test --pep8 searchV.py**  gives error

appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pep8.py:110: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
EXTRANEOUS_WHITESPACE_REGEX = re.compile(r'[[({] | []}),;:]')
===============test session starts =========================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.6, pytest-6.2.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: D:\work\py-modules
plugins: pep8-1.0.6
***collected 0 items / 1 error***

=============== ERRORS =======================================================
_______________ERROR collecting test session ____
Direct construction of Pep8Item has been deprecated, please use Pep8Item.from_parent.
See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#node-construction-changed-to-node-from-parent for more details.
==========short test summary info ===============
ERROR
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Here's the code in serachV.py

```
def search_letter(phrase: str , letter:str='aeiou')->set:
    """ Serach for letter in phrase"""
    return set(letter).intersection(set(phrase))
```

Not sure why no items are collected ?

Comment: Do you have any tests that can be collected? Also, you seem to use pytest-pep8, which is a very old and outdated plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tried `pep8 searchV.py` instead of Instead of `py.test --pep8 searchV.py`  and it worked.

But pep8 has been renamed to pycodestyle (GitHub issue #466) . Use of the pep8 tool will be removed in a future release.

So , I used pycodestyle and it worked !

```
pycodestyle searchV.py
```